# Start nagios web interface on a different port

Tags: network-monitoring, nagios3

I am trying to install nagios but I would like to start the web interface on a port other than 80. I cant seem to find much info on how to do that. Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just worked on this, and figured it out.  It's not ideal for some, but for me it works perfect.  I just changed the default port apache2 looks at by :

Changing /etc/apache2/sites-available/default
First line ( Default )  :

```
 <VirtualHost *:80>
```

Changed to :

```
 <VirtualHost *:8085>  # Change 8085 to whatever port you want
```

then linking default in sites-enabled ( not sure if this site is needed, but it works )

```
 cd /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/
 ln -s ../sites-available/default default
```

then cycle apache2 by :

```
 sudo service apache2 restart
```

Then test it out!  This is what worked for me, hopefully it works for you.

Answer (score 3):

If you have other web pages or apps running on the same server, the following information might be useful to separate Nagios as it's own Apache virtual host on a non-standard port (for example 43326 here).

Remove standard config and create Apache virtual host;

```
sudo cp /etc/apache2/conf.d/nagios.conf /etc/apache2/sites-available/nagios3
sudo rm /etc/apache2/conf.d/nagios.conf
sudo vi /etc/apache2/sites-available/nagios3
```

To beginning of file add;

```
Listen 43326
<VirtualHost *:43326>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/nagios3
```

To the end of the file add;

```
</VirtualHost>
```

Enable the new site;

```
sudo a2ensite nagios3
```

If you run a firewall (UFW), open the port;

```
sudo ufw allow 43326
```

Restart Apache

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```